# Comptablity of web3J with infura

Tags: java, rx-java2, blockchain, ethereum, web3-java

Is it possible to listen to infura events , using web3J ? 
I am trying to get events , but getting error

````
Caused by: org.web3j.protocol.core.filters.FilterException: Invalid request: The method eth_newFilter does not exist/is not available
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.filters.Filter.throwException(Filter.java:172)
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.filters.Filter.run(Filter.java:53)
    at org.web3j.protocol.rx.JsonRpc2_0Rx.run(JsonRpc2_0Rx.java:73)
    at org.web3j.protocol.rx.JsonRpc2_0Rx.lambda$ethLogFlowable$2(JsonRpc2_0Rx.java:65)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCreate.subscribeActual(FlowableCreate.java:71)
    ... 9 more```

# This is java wrappeer function generated by web3j maven plugin
````

```
public Flowable<PunkOfferedEventResponse>         punkOfferedEventFlowable(DefaultBlockParameter startBlock, DefaultBlockParameter endBlock) {
        EthFilter filter = new EthFilter(startBlock, endBlock, getContractAddress());
        filter.addSingleTopic(EventEncoder.encode(PUNKOFFERED_EVENT));
        return punkOfferedEventFlowable(filter);
    }


  public static class PunkOfferedEventResponse {
        public Log log;

        public BigInteger punkIndex;

        public String toAddress;

        public BigInteger minValue;
    }
```

```
# This is the caller which subscribe to punkOfferedEventFlowable andd it should iddeally return events in stream fashion 

Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService(""));
Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion = web3j.web3ClientVersion().send();
Credentials credentials = Credentials.create("");
            CryptoPunksMarket contract = CryptoPunksMarket.load("",web3j,credentials,new DefaultGasProvider()); contract.punkOfferedEventFlowable(null)
                 .doOnError(error -> error.printStackTrace())
                 .subscribe(event -> {
                     BigInteger index = event.punkIndex;
                     System.out.println("Index:"+index);
                 }).dispose();
```

I read in different blogs that it is not possible to get filtered events using web3J , then what are the alternatives available using web3J and infura to get the filtered events ?

Comment: You can try to use web socket to connect to the network instead of http/https.

Comment: Filters are not supported on Infura. You need to fetch each transaction receipt and look at the logs. The alternative is that you run your own node and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the events from the logs. Web3j provides a method `ethGetLogs`, which takes an ethFilter object as parameter and responses a list of event logs.

For your request it would be something like this:

```
EthFilter ethFilter = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, contract.getContractAddress());

ethFilter.addSingleTopic(EventEncoder.encode(CryptoPunksMarket.PUNK_OFFERED_EVENT));

EthLog ethLog = web3j.ethGetLogs(ethFilter).send();
```